# how to change the field value of selected feature in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I want to change the field value of the field 'Wtype' if the feature is selected. My current code is not working:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()


for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
    layer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), layer.fields().indexFromName('Wtype'),'Schakelwoning')


layer.commitChanges()
```

[image]

Comment: Your code seems ok, how are you using it ?

Comment: Isn't it getSelectedFeatures instead of selectedFeatures ?

Comment: @Louis Cottereau I select the features by hand and then i press the run script button

Comment: @ JULESG , you are right! thx!